# Utilizing Access and VBA: copying information between forms

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2003

Searched around a bit and could not find an existing post with my exact question.

I am creating an Access (2003) database utilizing multiple forms and tables that need to communicate and share information with one another (i.e. - first/last name, etc.).  The main form/table, "Personnel", will hold a majority of the information, yet the other forms/tables will only hold information pertinent to certain situations/circumstances, so not every entry in "Personnel" will have a concurrent entry in "Hired", for example.  If a record with the same name already exists, I would like a MsgBox to tell me so and open that entry (in the form, for editing), if not a new entry would be created, auto-populated with pre-selected fields (i.e. - first/last name).

After an option is selected from a pull-down menu, the appropriate form is accessed/opened, "Hired", for example (This part works).

The copying information across forms does not work.

---

```
Dim rstPers, rstHired As DAO.recordset
Dim LastName As String

If status = "hired" Then
DoCmd.OpenForm "Hired Information"

Set rstPers Forms!Personnel.RecordsetClone
Set rstHired Forms![Hired Information].RecordsetClone

????

...
End If
```

---

I have tried to do this multiple ways but nothing seems to work.  Nothing populates in the new Form or table.  Am I looking at it the wrong way?  Should I try a different approach?

Hope my explanation makes sense.  Thanks for any help.

-Charles

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad approach indeed.
Your forms are linked to a table. So you should avoid as much as possible to manipulate or retrieve **a form's data** directly using a recordsetclone, instead try to retrieve this data **directly from the table**.

So if you want to open your "hired information" form:

```
Dim RS As Recordset
Dim IDperson As String

IDperson = me.ID ' or whatever

Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID FROM TableHired WHERE ID='" & IDperson & "'")

If RS.BOF Then
    ' No record exist - Open form in record creation
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormHired", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
Else
    ' record exists, open form and position it oon the record's ID
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormHired", acNormal, , "ID='" & RS!ID & "'", acFormEdit
End If
```

Of course it won't work like this as you didn't provide enough info. 
Review this code and adapt it with your fields name (IDs), table name (TableHired) and FormName (FormHired) and following the situation on where and how you will trigger it. Also if your ID is not a string, you should remove the quotes in the SQL

Comment: I guess I should expound on what I am trying to do as a whole.